# Is Cloud Run limited by cold starts and maximum execution length?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

When using cloud functions we have the limitations related to cold starts and the maximum execution length of 9 minutes. Does any of these limitations also exist on Google Cloud Run?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas#resource_limits_for), there is a limit of 15 minutes before a timeout.

Cloud Run still has cold starts, but they are much less frequent that Cloud Functions, depending on your traffic patterns and the configured level of concurrency for an instance (max 80 concurrent requests, also from the documentation).